# Use awk to extract value from a line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have these two lines within a file:

```
<first-value system-property="unique.setting.limit">3</first-value>
<second-value-limit>50000</second-value-limit>
```

where I'd like to get the following as output using awk or sed:

```
3    
50000
```

Using this sed command does not work as I had hoped, and I suspect this is due to the presence of the quotes and delimiters in my line entry.

```
sed -n '/WORD1/,/WORD2/p' /path/to/file
```

How can I extract the values I want from the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}' input.txt
```

input.txt:

```
<first-value system-property="unique.setting.limit">3</first-value>
<second-value-limit>50000</second-value-limit>
```

Output:

```
3
50000
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I could set multiple field separators.

Comment: @martin More generally, you can use [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*limit"*>([0-9]+)<.*/\1/' file
```

Explanation:
`.*` takes care of everything that comes before the string *limit*

`limit"*` takes care of both the lines, one with `limit"` and the other one with just `limit`

`([0-9]+)` takes care of matching numbers and only numbers as stated in your requirement.

`\1` is actually a shortcut for capturing pattern. When a pattern groups all or part of its content into a pair of parentheses, it captures *that* content and stores it temporarily in memory. For more details, please refer https://www.inkling.com/read/introducing-regular-expressions-michael-fitzgerald-1st/chapter-4/capturing-groups-and

Comment: Lots of people write `sed -E` to mean `--extended-regexp`. This is the correct short option for **grep**, but not for **sed**. In **sed** (at least in **GNU sed**), the correct short form for `--regexp-extended` is `-r`. The POSIX norm [specifies `-E` for **grep**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html), but [nothing for **sed**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). And **sed**'s manpage clearly indicates `-r`, with no mention of `-B`. Besides, your suggested solution, as many here, doesn't work with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
        sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z.<\/>= \-]//g' file
```

Comment: This solution isn't suitable if you have digits within the `< ... >` tags, because it will keep them and concatenate them to the actual number the OP wants to extract.

Answer (score 0):

The script solution with parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line || test -n "$line" ; do
    value="${line%<*}"
    printf "%s\n" "${value##*\>}"
done <"$1"
```

**output:**

```
$ ./ltags.sh dat/ltags.txt
3
50000
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like XML to me, so assuming it forms part of some valid XML, e.g.

```
<root>
<first-value system-property="unique.setting.limit">3</first-value>
<second-value-limit>50000</second-value-limit>
</root>
```

You can use Perl's [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) and do something like this:

```
perl -MXML::Simple -E '$xml = XMLin("file"); say $xml->{"first-value"}->{"content"}; say $xml->{"second-value-limit"}'
```

Output:

```
3
50000
```

If the XML structure is more complicated, then you may have to drill down a bit deeper to get to the values you want. If that's the case, you should edit the question to show the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Ashkan's **awk** solution is straightforward, but let me suggest a **sed** solution that accepts non-integer numbers:

```
sed -n 's/[^>]*>\([.[:digit:]]*\)<.*/\1/p' input.txt
```

This extracts the number between the first `>` character of the line and the following `<`. In my RE this "number" can be the empty string, if you don't want to accept an empty string please add the `-r` option to **sed** and replace `\([.[:digit:]]*\)` by `([.[:digit:]]+)`.